# Rotate Back of Flashcard 180 Degrees

Tags: rotating, flashcards

I'm trying to modify a LaTeX file I found that uses the flashcard package:

```
\documentclass[avery5371,grid]{flashcards}
```

What packages would I need to add in order to rotate the back of each card by 180 degrees? Can you give a code snippet for the following?

```
\begin{flashcard}[Theorem]{properties of absolute values}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $|ab| = |a||b|$
\item $\left| \dfrac{a}{b} \right| = \dfrac{|a|}{|b|}$
\item $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$
\item $|a-b| \geq ||a| - |b||$
\end{enumerate}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\end{flashcard}
```

Comment: This is just a suggestion but you may want to look into the `tcolorbox` package to produce similar flash cards. The result will be easier to customize.

Answer (score 0):

This involves mucking about with the internals of `flashcards` and it's completely untested (my laptop had to go back in for repairs, grr), but I think it will work.

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\flashcards@beginframebox}{\begin{turn}{180}}
\renewcommand{\flashcards@endframebox}{\end{turn}{180}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I plan to print double sided flashcards, so that when I cut them out, I will be able to flip them on the horizontal axis, then back side will read properly. The solution you offered rotates everything --both front and back side- by 180 degrees.

Comment: As I noted, this was untested... I'd have to dig deeper into the internals of the package to see where to incorporate the rotation, but any solution will require such digging.